# How to configure DHCPv6 and DNSv6 configuration in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, dhcp, ipv6, isc-dhcp

I'm planning to configure DHCPv6 and DNS server in my network.

1. I would like to understand whether both DHCPv4 and DHCPv6 can be configured using isc-dhcp-server service?
2. When i tried nslookup domainname it returned the IPv4 address instead of ipv6 address.
3. When i tried to configure two IPv6 IP for the two different
   interfaces for the same machine,only one interface was coming up
   with the IP.Is there any norms need to be followed when configuring
   IP?( The network is a private network and i dont need internet
   connectivity)

Can someone guide me to configure the dhcpv6 and DNS server for IPv6?

Info for #1 Query
    # This is a very basic subnet declaration.

```
 subnet 10.222.190.0 netmask 255.255.255.192 {
 range 10.222.190.54 10.222.190.61;
#  option routers rtr-239-0-1.example.org, rtr-239-0-2.example.org;
}

 subnet6 2001:1:1:1::0 netmask 64 {
 range6 2001:1:1:1::15 2001:1:1:1::35;
#  option routers rtr-239-0-1.example.org, rtr-239-0-2.example.org;
}
```

Info for #3 query.

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:f4:63:54
          inet addr:10.222.190.55  Bcast:10.222.190.63  Mask:255.255.255.192
          inet6 addr: 2001:1:1:1::9/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fef4:6354/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:77414 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:234 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:5207783 (5.2 MB)  TX bytes:32631 (32.6 KB)

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:38:fc:87
          inet addr:10.222.190.70  Bcast:10.222.190.127  Mask:255.255.255.192
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe38:fc87/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:174 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:45035 (45.0 KB)  TX bytes:988 (988.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:268 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:268 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:20504 (20.5 KB)  TX bytes:20504 (20.5 KB)
```

Interface config file

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp

# Primary entry node Enterprise NAT
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.222.190.55
netmask 255.255.255.192
network 10.222.190.0
broadcast 10.222.190.63
gateway 10.222.190.1

iface eth1 inet6 static
address 2001:1:1:1::9
#address fd01:1:1:1::9
netmask 64
gateway 2001:1:1:1::1

# Exit Node Access NAT
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet static
address 10.222.190.70
netmask 255.255.255.192
network 10.222.190.64
broadcast 10.222.190.127
gateway 10.222.190.65

iface eth2 inet6 static
address 2001:1:1:2::6
#address fd01:1:1:2::6
netmask 64
gateway 2001:1:1:2::1
```

IPv6 Planning carried out:

```
Interface name  Eth:IP Address  Gateway IP  Routing Prefix
ETH2    2001:1:1:1::6   2001:1:1:1::1   64
ETH1    2001:1:1:1::7   2001:1:1:1::1   64
ETH4    2001:1:1:1::8   2001:1:1:1::1   64
ETH1    2001:1:1:1::9   2001:1:1:1::1   64
ETH2    2001:1:1:2::6   2001:1:1:2::1   64
ETH4    2001:1:1:2::7   2001:1:1:2::1   64
ETH3    2001:1:1:2::8   2001:1:1:2::1   64
ETH4    2001:1:1:2::9   2001:1:1:2::1   64
ETH0    2001:1:1:2::10  2001:1:1:2::1   64
ETH0    2001:1:1:2::11  2001:1:1:2::1   64
ETH1    2001:1:1:3::6   2001:1:1:3::1   64
ETH5    2001:1:1:3::7   2001:1:1:3::1   64
ETH4    2001:1:1:3::8   2001:1:1:3::1   64
ETH5    2001:1:1:3::9   2001:1:1:3::1   64
```

Comment: Don't use other people's public IPv6 addresses. For your private network, use a Unique Local Address block instead.

Comment: Can you please guide me? i will update the current ipv6 planning done in the original query,Please provide your valuable suggestions to correct it.